# Swig typemaps with smart pointers

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have the following c++ class:

```
class Entity : public Watchable
{
public:
    [...]
    std::string value() const
    {
        return "Entity::value()";
    }
};

Entity* create_entity_pointer()
{
    return new Entity();
}

watch_ptr<Entity> create_entity_watch_pointer()
{
    return watch_ptr<Entity>(new Entity());
}
```

... and the following SWIG typemap declaration:

```
%typemap(out) std::string Entity::value
{
    $result = PyString_FromString("Typemapped value");
}
```

The [watch_ptr class](https://github.com/kermado/SwigSmartPtrs/blob/master/watch_ptr.hpp) is exposed to Python and I declare all of the possible types that can be wrapped:

```
%template(EntityWatchPtr) watch_ptr<Entity>;
```

This works as expected when calling the attribute function on an `Entity*` from Python. However, SWIG ignores the typemap when called on a `watch_ptr<Entity>`. My python script is as below:

```
from module import *
player1 = create_entity_pointer()
print(player1)
print(player1.value())
player2 = create_entity_watch_pointer()
print(player2)
print(player2.value())
```

This produces the following output:

```
<module.Entity; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Entity *' at 0x100b15ba0> >
Typemapped value
<module.EntityWatchPtr; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'watch_ptr< Entity > *' at 0x100b613c0> >
Entity::value()
```

How can I get the typemap working with smart pointers?
I have put the full source code online: https://github.com/kermado/SwigSmartPtrs

Comment: Do you have some code to demonstrate what works and what is ignored?

Comment: I have provided some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some experimentation, it seems that the typemaps must be specified **before** the SWIG template declarations. In other words, I needed to declare:

```
%template(EntityWatchPtr) watch_ptr<Entity>;
```

**before** the typemap:

```
%typemap(out) std::string Entity::value
{
    $result = PyString_FromString("Typemapped value");
}
```

in my SWIG interface file. The output of my program is then:

```
<module.Entity; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Entity *' at 0x10b7b3ba0> >
Typemapped value
<module.EntityWatchPtr; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'watch_ptr< Entity > *' at 0x10b7ff3c0> >
Typemapped value
```